# How strong is a weak equality?

Tags: functional-analysis

Title is vague, but I couldn't come up with a better. Suggestions are appreciated.

I'm wondering how strong a weak equality is, which of course will depend on the definition of weak in this case, so let me rephrase to a more specific scenario:

Let $ f, g \in L^2(\Omega)^n $ where $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n $ is a bounded domain. Suppose "$ f = g $" weakly in the sense that $ (f,\nabla \phi)_{L^2} = (g,\nabla \phi)_{L^2} $ for all $ \phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega) $. 
Is this equality strong enough that $ \|f\cdot h\|_{L^2} = \|g\cdot h\|_{L^2} $ for all $ h \in L^2(\Omega)^n $ whenever $ \|f\cdot h\|_{L^2} < \infty $?

To be specific: "$ \cdot $" is simply the $ \mathbb R^n $ inner product.

I feel like the answer here is probably 'not in general', but no immediate counter example has sprung to my mind.

Comment: Doesn't your "$f=g$ weakly" assumptions imply that $f=g$ in $L^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f,g \in W^{1,2}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n)$ being elements of the $W^{1,2}$-Sobolev-space, we have $$(\mathrm{div}f,\phi) = (f,\nabla \phi) = (g, \nabla \phi) = (\mathrm{div}g,\phi)$$ for $L^2$-functions $\mathrm{div}f, \mathrm{div}g$. By the fundamental theorem of the calculus of variations this is equivalent to $\mathrm{div}f = \mathrm{div}g$. Hence $f$ and $g$ may differ by any divergence-free term, for example $f = g + \nabla \Lambda$ for a smooth function $\Lambda$.

**In conclusion**: Your "weak equality" only implies that the weak derivates (or distributional derivaties) coincide. Neither more, nor less.